# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for https requests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, exchangewebservices

Unable to make https `XMLHttpRequest` requests - getting this back:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:8443' is therefore not allowed access.`

If I replace the url with `www.google.com`, it's fine, but `https://www.google.com` does the same thing.

It works when I use Postman/JaSON Chrome extensions, so I tried `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`, but that didn't work either.

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + asyncResult.value);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type, Origin");
request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
request.onload = function() {

};
request.onerror = function() {
    debugger;
}
request.send(requestBody);
```

Comment: The server sets CORs not the JavaScript

Comment: I'm guessing `outlook.office365.com` is not your domain, and you can't do cross origin ajax for security reasons *(unless the **server** sends CORS headers )*.

Comment: @adeneo yeah it's from `localhost` right now, but still need to send a request to `outlook.office365.com` to get data

Answer (score 0):

The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is set server-side for security reasons.

If you had access to the server you could just do:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

This, however, is not safe for obvious reasons. You should always allow as minimum external access as possible.

Recently I had the same issue. What I did was just use my own server, make the request from there to the api, and just have the script make the request to my server instead (from which you can set the access control header). So basically, instead of making the request to the third party client-side (from javascript), make it server-side and then get that data from your server via javascript.